# Match a single word only, on a line, using regex pattern

Tags: vim

I am trying to write a very simple function that would match a single word at the start of a line, for writing prose. It would then `center` and move down a line `+1`.  But I've having problems with the regex syntax.

```
function! Testing()
    let line=getline('.')
    if line =~ ^\w+(\s+|$)
        center
        +1
    else
        center
        +1
    endif
endfunction
```

this would ultimately be because the if statement will have additions that will `upperword`, and `indent4`, placing the cursor inside quotes

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for

```
if line =~ "^\w\+\>"
```

[image: before]
[image: calling]
[image]

Comment: no, this is not producing anything?

Comment: Here, by replacing this line in the appropriate place of your function, it perfectly centers the current line when calling the function. Oh, but I forgot: the function should be ended with endfunction, not "end function".

Comment: ye its just a copy over error that, I've amended it. its not doing anything still, is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: You should give some sample lines to that you are trying with. I suppose what you mean by "word" is different from what word is meant by regexp word.

Comment: just one word on a line? at the start of the line. followed by nothing until the end of the line. ?

Comment: No. The line can be anything but it must start with a string containing only _ 0-9 A-Z a-z characters.  No other character is taken a "word" character in regexp terminology. Should you have any punctuation for example, no match will happen. So really, some example may help...

Comment: Yes that is all i need, there is no punctuation, it is a title. Specifically for character titles in a screen play. At the moment i am typing a name of the character then gUU to uppercase manually, then i have a func that centers and drops me a line, for dialogue. i am just trying to automate this process.
`^character$`

Comment: the pattern you have given is more than one word isn't it?

Comment: No, the pattern matches exactly one or more word characters (that is ONE word) from the beginning of the line until the boundary of the world. The boundary can be any non-word (not in [_0-9A-Za-z]) character or the end of the line.

Comment: sorry, you do recognise there is a difference between one word, and one word or more though don't you? \w is essentially shorthand for `[A-Za-z0-9_]` isn't it?

Comment: centre works on all words on the line by default.

Comment: The match is done on the first word as you wished but the center is done on the line whose first word is matched. If you did not want this, then either of us is lost a bit.